# Having trouble getting circular buttons in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I used this fiddle directly in my code. The idea is to create a circular button.

https://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/59e5e1ya/

This code is for bootstrap 3 though. When using it referencing bootstrap 4, the button is square rather than circular. Here's an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/NibblyPig/fsedc5p6/

The CSS that it is applying is:

```
.btn-circle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
}
```

As with all buttons I set the classes to `btn` and `btn-success` (or similar) as well as this class too.

Checking the inspector, it is definitely applying this, however something must be overriding or changing this behaviour because it still appears square.

I am unable to find any explanation or working code via google that will produce a circular button in bootstrap 4. Is there any advice?

Comment: I'm not sure, both ur jsfiddles have a circular button, are those both BS3 examples or? anyway, applying `border-radius: 50%;` doesn't get the job done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the `.btn-success` was overriding with a `border-color`. You can target them both using `.btn-success.btn-circle`. Also try to override the hover styles.

Added CSS:

```
.btn-circle.btn-success {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.btn-circle.btn-success:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

[JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/725dscxq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Need to Update `-webkit-appearance: none;`

Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f46ab37x/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<button></button>`  then Just add `border-radius:50%!important` and `padding: 1.375rem 0.75rem!important;` to `.btn`.

```css
.btn {
  border-radius: 50%!important;
  padding: 1.375rem 0.75rem!important;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Danger</button>
```

Comment: Adding that CSS into the jsfiddle does not give a circular button https://jsfiddle.net/NibblyPig/fsedc5p6/1/

Comment: @NibblyPig Actually it works for button.As you see in jsfiddle that was a link of type button.
I have given the solution for `<button>` .If you check by placing any of the button tag it will work. I thought this would work if you were using buttons. Updated my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just do a bootstrap trick that always work. Here is how

```
button class="btn btn-success rounded-circle"> $$ </button>
```

basically just add `rounded-circle` to the class.